# Converting plain text input into char to get numerical value of letter to shift by 5?

Tags: java

Basically I am doing a Caesar Cipher where I need to change the letter by -6 places (so G becomes A etc) in java. I have a scanner set up to capture the text, but I do not know how to convert the text to its numerical value to do the actual shift. I can just receive input and then print out the same output.

Can you help me with the code for the shift?

I know it has something to do with the char function, but have no idea what to do next.

Comment: could post the code that you've tried?

Comment: The way to go around this is to usually to change the string into an array of characters. Once that you have the character, you can type cast it to an int.

Comment: And F should become Z? Please clear it.

Comment: @AdarshAnurag Yes.

Comment: @ArunKumarMN I have not tried anything yet, just found some complex examples online, but each one is very different to each other!

Comment: @npinti How do I convert the string into an array of characters in Java?

Comment: just call toCharArray() from the string object

Comment: @JSpractice: Usually somthing of the sort: `for int i = 0; i < str.kength; i++) { char c = str.charAt(i); int numberAsChar = (int) c;}`.

Comment: @ArunKumarMN Something like Caesarinput.toCharArray() ? Can you type a quick example?

Comment: String x="abc"; char[] arr=c.toCharArray();

Comment: @JSpractice If `String x="abc";` it will return `uvw` ?

Comment: use Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(<UR stream>);// ex System.in
int ch = reader.read(); to get the char by char, do your operation based on value .

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
public class Cipher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        String x = scan.next();
        int shift_position = -6;
        String converted = "";
        for (char c : x.toCharArray()) {
            char newchar = (char) (c + shift_position);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c) && newchar < 65)
                newchar = (char) (newchar + 26);
            else if (Character.isLowerCase(c) && newchar < 97)
                newchar = (char) (newchar + 26);
             else if(c==' ') newchar=c;
            converted += Character.toString(newchar);
        }
        System.out.println(converted);
    }
}
```

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
      Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class HelpToo

Comment: add 
import java.util.Scanner;

Comment: Thanks. It does not work with sentences that have spaces in them

Comment: sorry i forgot space character

Comment: add  else block after if
   
else newchar=c;

Comment: Else what? Sorry very new to programming!

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: Still does not work, cuts off at first space.

Comment: cuts off at first space for example?

Comment: You else newchar=c, just breaks the cipher, does not change any letters. Only until first space means: "Try again" is "Nls".

Comment: else if(c==' ') newchar=c;

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this code. Code is self sufficient in explaining the approach applied.

```
import java.util.*;
class help
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //initializing Scanner class object
        String string = sc.nextLine(),string2=""; //use nextLine for reading with spaces.
        int i,l;
        l = string.length();
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            char c = string.charAt(i); // getting character at position i

            if(c==' ') // if character is space
            {
                string2 = string2 + c; //add it to string2
                continue; // then move to next iteration for next character
            }

            int ascii = (int)c; // converting character into its equivalent ascii value.
            //Ascii value can be considered as a numerical value for every character. 
            //Operations on Ascii value will help us get desired changes.

            if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
            {
                int nVal = ascii - 65; // ascii value of A is 65
                nVal = (nVal + 20)%26; // going back 6 letters is equivalent to moving 20 letters ahead
                nVal = 65 + nVal;
                string2 = string2 + (char)nVal;
            }
            else
            {
                int nVal = ascii - 97; // ascii value of a is 97
                nVal = (nVal + 20)%26;
                nVal = 97 + nVal;
                string2 = string2 + (char)nVal;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(string2);
    }
}
```

The code is producing following outputs for the inputs as shown below:

```
Input: Toon
Output: Niih
```

```
Input: FGfg
Output: ZAza
```

```
Input: zA aZ
Output: tU uT
```

Comment: Does not work when string has a space in it.

Comment: @JSpractice See now. I hope you do not have to apply shift on spaces.

Comment: No, spaces are just spaces.

Comment: @JSpractice It will work. It will leave spaces as spaces

Comment: @JSpractice If you have any doubts in the code, I will clarify them.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to try in JDK 8.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] srg) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String originalString = scan.nextLine();
    String newString =
        originalString
            .codePoints()
            .map(
                character -> {
                  if (character != ' ') return character - 6;
                  else return character;
                })
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
    System.out.println(newString);
  }
}
```